# Ordering 2 columns on the same order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table:

Example:

```
Name       |      Last Name
Albert            Rigs
Carl              Dimonds
Robert            Big
Julian            Berg
```

I need to order like this:

```
Name       |      Last Name
Albert            Rigs         (name)
Julian            Berg         (last name)
Robert            Big          (last name)
Carl              Dimonds
```

I need something like, order by name and last name on the same ordering.
See on example, i have Name Albert, the next ordered name row its the Carl, but i have Big and Berg on last name, B > C so i get the last name order on second row.
It's like the two columns are the same but isn't.
It's hard to explaim, i'm sorry.

Its possible?

Thaks in advance.

Comment: Not completely sure I understand your ordering logic.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why would Big come before Berg?  I think @Andomar has the correct approach (assuming I'm understanding correctly).

Comment: you'r right. stupid fail my.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To order by the minimum of `(Name, Lastname)`, you could:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
order by
        case 
        when Name > LastName then LastName
        else name
        end
```

Comment: work's like a charm. ty very mutch. i don't knew i can use case on order like this, and don't knew string comparison on sql works like that.

Comment: OP = Original Poster.  The abbreviation used to denate "questioner" or "asker".  Unless you're a neuter, "its" not good ;-) j/k

Comment: @sgeddes , nice. OPs its me. ;)

Comment: Ty all for fast answer, and for be patient with my ignorance and bad english. lol it's becouse you guys SO it's the best place to be in ;)

Answer (score 3):

A syntactic improvement on the Case, and allowing a ti-break on the other column.

```
 select   *
 from     my_table
 order by least(name,last_name),
          greatest(name,last_name)
```

Comment: +1 This is simpler and better. The 2nd `ORDER BY` item breaks ties, which the other answer neglects.